# Using google drive as a central document store (Concept)

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-drive-api

I have a question, I have a customer who is enterprise customer at google. We are developing a website to manage service intervention/service manuals/reports as PDF.
What the customer want is a shared google drive where all the PDF are stored and each user have direct access to the PDF on the google drive form his browser.
We have to do is to upload the PDF from a website, so far so good.
I have been playing around with the ServiceAccountCredential in .net and it is working fine, uploading, creating etc. BUT !!

Since all files are uploaded with Service Account credential account, they  can not be easily be shared since there is no GUI interface etc. and we have to set the permission on each file and directory.

Is there a way to connect with a service account to an existing google drive account.

Thanks for your input

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) you can enable domain wide delegation and assume the identity of an account in the Google Domain. Once you have the identity of an account you can pick up the file and set the shares on the file.

Use the [Google Client Libraries to set up the shares](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)

Comment: Hi Jasper thanks for the reply, how do I link a serviceaccount access to an account, or assume the identity. If I use the normal Oatuh, the user has to approve the access to this account

Comment: You need to go through the documentation for that. I could not find a quickstart for .NET. The point of a service account is machine to machine communication, where you do not have a user to authenticate the request. Try to find some .NET examples and read the documentation.

Comment: Hi Found the way to do it now, you need go get perment access to one drive account and say the credentials, then it works, thanks a lot